# How do I remove HTML tags from within a text area using MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have difficulty getting a value from a text area of the `CKEditor`
when I save something that has nothing inside the textarea HTML tag. In this case, it puts this text inside:

```
<html>\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t\t<title></title>\r\n\t</head>\r\n\t<body>\r\n\t</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

Is there some way to strip off all these html tags?

I'm using `MVC 3`, and I've researched something about: `Content(Server.HtmlEncode)`,
but I'm still not 100% if this is the best way to do this kind of treatment.

Comment: If you don't want HTML tags, why are you using CKEditor?

Comment: ta whole problem there .. order because it was the head .. and the client have to remove this type of tag to check if is empty or not

Comment: What is the end result you are looking for?  DO you just need to check to see if a tag is empty or???  Nevermind the stripping of the html...whats the goal from stripping off the html?

Comment: Goal is to make sure it is empty ... of a way I'm using is picking up the html tag it ta generating and making the comparison.

Comment: But wanted to know if would have any way to remove the html tag that it generates

Comment: try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734877/remove-html-formatting-in-razor-mvc-3

Answer (score 3):

I found a class listed below that looks like it should solve your problem.  Just add it to your solution and you can then call it statically and strip the html.

This kind of assumes that you are wanting to do the stripping of html on the server side.

*On a side note not accepting answers like you are doing is hazardous to people willingness to help...I'd recommend that you reward the people that are helping you if you'd like to continue getting help!*

[Link to Solution](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```html
  @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.content)
```